# Cleanest way to filter items from list which are not present in another nested list

Tags: python, list

I am trying to find a cleanest way to filter items from list which are not present in another list of lists.

In the below example, I need to get elements from `list_start` which are not present inside `lists_test`:

```
list_start = ["paris", "manchester", "tokyo", "singapour", "berlin"]
lists_test = [["berlin", "manchester"], ["tokyo", "lille"]]

result = ["paris", "singapour"]
```

Do you have an idea to achieve this without using multiple `for ... in:` to get result?

Comment: you could consider flattening the lists_tests to a set and then compare against that.

Comment: Also do you have a typo? `["tokyo', 'lille"]` this is a list with only one item, as you have used two different qoute markers in it. Is this meant to be two items? `["tokyo", "lille"]`

Comment: @ChrisDoyle yes, two items, sorry, think flattening the list_tests is a good idea

Answer (score 2):

If your goal is to find unique values, you could use `set()`

```py
list_start = ["paris", "manchester", "tokyo", "singapour", "berlin"]
lists_test = [["berlin", "manchester"], ["tokyo", "lille"]]
f=[]
list(map(f.extend, lists_test)) #flatten second list
list(set(list_start)-set(f))
```

Answer (score 2):

If you do not care about the order of elements in the initial list, then you may use [`set()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#func-set) with [`itertools.chain()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain) as:

```
from itertools import chain

list_start = ["paris", "manchester", "tokyo", "singapour", "berlin"]
lists_test = [["berlin", "manchester"], ["tokyo", "lille"]]

final = set(list_start) - set(chain(*lists_test))
# final = list(final)  ## if you need to type cast `set` object to `list`
```

where `final` will hold:

```
['paris', 'singapour']
```

**Explanation**: `set(A) - set(B)` returns the elements present in `A` but not in `B`.

Comment: I like this answer cause i always forget about itertools.chain

Answer (score 1):

You can use a simple list comprehension, using all() as condition:

```
list_start = ["paris", "manchester", "tokyo", "singapour", "berlin"]
lists_test = [["berlin", "manchester"], ["tokyo", "lille"]]

result=[i for i in list_start if all(i not in k for k in lists_test)]

print(result)
```

Output:

```
['paris', 'singapour']
```